# Keystone configuration file permissions

Tags: security, openstack, keystone, juju

I'm playing around with Juju and OpenStack and I installed Keystone Identity service on one of the nodes. SSH-ing into the machine I noticed that the permissions of the configuration file `/etc/keystone/keystone.conf` are 644 (`rw-r--r--`) which means it is readable by any user on the system.

Keeping in mind that this file contains the `MySQL` username and password, wouldn't be it right the file to be readable only by the `keystone` user?

Note that I've tried installing using both Juju and by hand using a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 with the same results.

Edit: Forgot to mention that OpenStack documentation doesn't mention anything about permissions in its [docs](http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any other openstack services use keystone.conf. So you may change ownership to keystone and change permission so that only keystone can read.

```
chown keystone:keystone /etc/keystone/keystone.conf

chmod 600 /etc/keystone/keystone
```

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's the only service that's using this file. The question is more about isn't this in fact a bug and should be reported? I also wonder whether this type of bugs are affecting other OpenStack services.

Comment: Yes, you may report this as bug. I can also see other conf like swift,glance with 644 permission.